# Where em um array

Tags: php, mysql, sql, array

Tenho a seguinte **Query:**

```
SELECT u.user_nome
FROM tb_Usuario u
WHERE u.user_ativo = 1
```

Preciso mais uma cláusula `where` onde a mesma comparar um `id` do usuário. Porém, recebo esse `id` através de um `array`, como faço para fazer essa comparação?

**Array**:

```
(
  [0] => 1-funil-pr-
  [1] => 3-funil-pr-2
)
```

Recebo estes dois parâmetros `id`.

Comment: vê isto http://stackoverflow.com/questions/907806/php-mysql-using-an-array-in-where-clause @Fred

Comment: esse array é recebido pelo fetch_array ou esse array vem de outro lugar, está um pouco confuso

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Resolvido!

```
$recebe_do_controller = $data->recebe_do_controller; //DADOS RECEBIDOS DO CONTROLLER
$array_explode = explode(',', $recebe_do_controller); //FIZ O EXPLODE NO ARRAY PRQ PRECISEI UTILIZÁ-LO EM OUTRAS FUNÇÕES.
$array_implode = "('".implode("','", $array_explode)."')"; //IMPLODE ARRAY PARA PODER UTILIZAR AS INFORMAÇÕES NA QUERY

SELECT
 u.user_nome
FROM
 tb_Usuario u
WHERE
 u.user_ativo = 1 AND u.user_slug IN ".$array_implode.";
```

Comment: Esta solução permite injeção de código SQL. Veja esta pergunta: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3864/como-prevenir-inje%c3%a7%c3%a3o-de-c%c3%b3digo-sql-no-meu-c%c3%b3digo-php

Answer (score 2):

Pode usar a função `IN`, para mais informações veja no [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9476146/mysql-php-select-where-id-array) ou [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in), deixo um exemplo:

```
$array = array(1, 4, 5, 7);

$sql = 'SELECT * 
        FROM `table` 
        WHERE `id` IN (' . implode(',', array_map('intval', $array)) . ')';
```

Answer (score 1):

A respostas do @Tmc funciona, porem utilizam concatenação de SQL, algo que considero não ser a melhor forma.
Recomendo utilizar `prepared Statements` conforme descrito [nesta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3864/como-prevenir-inje%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-c%C3%B3digo-sql-no-meu-c%C3%B3digo-php) pergunta.

A sua consulta pode ser feita da seguinte forma:

```
$arrTokens = ["1", "18", "35"];
$qtdElementos = count($arrTokens);
$arrInterrogacoes = array_fill("0", $qtdElementos, "?");

$sql = "SELECT u.user_nome FROM tb_Usuario u WHERE u.user_ativo = 1 AND u.user_slug IN (";
$sql .= implode(",", $arrInterrogacoes);
$sql .= ")";

$statement = $suaConexaoPDO->prepare($sql);

for($i = 0; $i < $qtdElementos; $i++) {
  $statement->bindValue($i, $arrTokens[$i]);
}

$statement->execute();
```